# Ethernet disrupted my automatic Wi-Fi+VPN connection

Tags: boot, wireless, network-manager, ethernet, openvpn

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 with Gnome on my company laptop and everything was working just fine: got my automatic wi-fi + VPN setup and it ran smoothly every time. I also configured my hosts file with a lot of company-related IPs which I need to use.

However, a few days ago my Wi-Fi connection was a bit clunky and I tried plugging in an Ethernet cable. At first everything went fine. However, after finishing my job and unplugging, I realised that every single time I boot I get a message saying that the connection has failed (referring to the missing Ethernet cable I assume) and neither my Wi-Fi nor my VPN are connected automatically anymore, causing some applications that load on start to not get the right info as there is no connection until I set it up manually.

I have deleted the Ethernet connection and I have checked the network settings many times, but I cannot manage to make it work as it did before I plugged the cable that one time. It really is tedious and annoying since I have to connect everything manually even after suspending the machine and then refresh the applications that were trying to fetch data once the laptop has connected to my allegedly-automatic Wi-Fi network.

Any tips?